# how do i use selenium to test javascript image upload?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, selenium, phpunit

I am using jquery MultiFile js to do an image upload function in an admin page.

I am implementing Selenium right now within phpunit.

I would like a detailed description of how to test the following scenario using Selenium:

1) access to /admin/products/new

2) fill in title textbox

3) click on upload image button

4) upload 2 images

5) hit overall submit button

6) redirect to /admin/products and check for success message

I am able to write assertElementPresent etc commands for steps 1-6 **except 3 and 4**.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're asking how to upload an image using Selenium. The default way of uploading images would be to use the typeKeys() method to pass the file name to the input file uploader.

1. Use Selenium to log in as an admin and browse to the /admin/products/new page.
2. If you're using RC, use typeKeys() to fill in the title textbox. If you're using WebDriver, use keys().
3. Upload an image by targeting it and sending the file name with typeKeys() or keys().
4. Refer to step 3.
5. Use Selenium to click the submit button.
6. waitForElementPresent on success message.